# Django filter model objects related to another model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to create a query set that matches a model objects, here's what i tried:

```
a = Product.objects.first() # Select first product as a test

b = a.compareproducts_set.all() # Filter only related product "a" in the query
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category_name = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True )
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True, unique=True) 

class CompareProducts(models.Model):
    
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    list1 = Product.objects.first()
    list2 = CompareProducts.objects.filter(product_id=list1.id)
    context = {
        'products': products, 'list1': list1, 'list2': list2
        }
    return render(request,'products/index.html', context)
```

Now i only have first product "a" and it's filtered related query set "b", how to iterate the rest products along with their filtered query set from second model?
So i can have two lists i can zip and loop them in template

Solution :

In Django templates I used :

```
{% for product in products %}
{{product.name}}<br>

{% for offer in product.compare_products.all %}

{{offer.product}} @ {{ offer.pharmacy.name }} for {{ offer.price}}<br>

{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

I added related_name "compare_products" tag to my Compareproducts model, in my views.py all I had to filter is :
products = Product.objects.all()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`products = Product.objects.filter(blah blah blah ).prefech_related('compareproducts_set')`
Will give you products based on the filters, and will feach all comparedproducts that have relation to each product in a single hit to DB.
Then to use compareproducts related to each product do smt like:

```
for p in products:
   p.compareproducts_set.all()
```

The full doc exists here, please read it:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

---

Also will be good if you add `related_name` to your fk fields to better access the reverse relation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category_name = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True, blank = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True, unique=True) 

class CompareProducts(models.Model):
    
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="campare_products") # add here
```

then

```
products = Product.objects.filter(blah blah blah ).prefech_related('compare_products') # change here
for p in products:
   p.compare_products.all()  # change here
```

P.S: I'm with a cellphone and maybe my answer have typo, so please follow documentations rather than using exact my code :)

Comment: I tried using this format
x = Product.objects.all().prefetch_related('compareproducts_set')
When printing x.values() nothing related to 'compareproducts' model is printed.

Comment: @AndroidMod
check my asnwer again, has been updated.

Comment: Thank you, found a solution very close to yours.

Comment: Good, put it as a answer here maybe be helpful for others.